# Cannot create a linked server to between two instances of SQL server 2016 running in a 2 node multisubnet windows failover cluster (WFCI)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, failovercluster

We have a 2 node windows failover cluster which is running two 'SQL Server 2016 SP3 std edition' instances (called CLA and CLB) OS is Windows server 2019.

The CLA instance is using the default port 1433 and the other is a named instance (CLB\MSSQL) and has been configured to use a static port of 1533.

It is a multi subnet failover cluster as the two windows nodes (and dependent resource IP's) in the cluster have different subnets.

Under normal usage windows node 1 will have CLA instance active and node 2 will have CLB\MSSQL instance active.

I can connect to both instances fine from SSMS but when I try to create a linked server from CLA linking to CLB and select 'SQL Server' as the server type

[linked server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYZnr.png)

The linked server gets created but when I try to expand it, it fails to connect to anything.

I've checked the browser service is running but as we are using the default port 1433 and the static port 1533 I don't believe think this is required when using TCPIP.

If I failover so both instances are running on the same node I am able to create the linked server and connect to it fine but as soon as the instance fails over the linked server connection no longer works.

When connecting to SSMS I have the multisubnetfailover=true 'Additonal Connection Parameter' set

[SSMS multisubnetfailover=true parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7EMA.png)
Have anybody running a failover cluster using multisubnet configuration had the same issue?